# List files in CMD with DIR

Tags: windows-7, command-line, dir

I'm trying to use `DIR` to list all files in the current directory and sub directories ordered alphabetically. I only care about the filepath and name. I don't want the size, counts, etc. Here's what I have but it's just too details:

```
dir/on/s/w/a-d > __files.txt
```

This outputs something like (obfuscated):

```
 Volume in drive Q is ********
 Volume Serial Number is ****-****

 Directory of Q:\****

__files.txt                    __listallfileswithoutput.bat
               2 File(s)             28 bytes

 Directory of Q:\****\*

*** ****.***           ******.***              ** **** ******.***
** **** ** ******.***   
               4 File(s)  4,288,735,526 bytes

 Directory of Q:\****\*

*********.***
 ...
```

I just want:

```
Q:\****\*\*** ****.***
Q:\****\*\******.***
Q:\****\*\** **** ******.***
Q:\****\*\** **** ** ******.***
Q:\****\*\*********.***
```

Can this be done with DIR alone? If not, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the output of `dir/on/s/a-d/b > __files.txt` what you expect?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. You should expand your answer to include the reasons why/how it works. FYI, I looked through the `DIR` help and completely overlooked `/b`! Thanks

Comment: Not sure what sort of reasons/explanation you're looking for, that a simple `dir /?` will not provide. /on sorts by name (alphabetic), /s is for dir recursion, /a-d omits dirs and /b is for a bare output format. The rest simply redirects the command's output to your chosen file.